# Help with syntax tree generation with movements

Tags: syntax-trees

[image]

This is my attempt at the sentence "Which compound appears to have been created with the recently found chemical element yesterday?" , but I'm not sure if it's correct:

1. Is the wh-movement correct? Does the whole DP "a compound" get moved, or just the NP "compound"?
2. Is "yesterday" an advP adjunct? Is it in the right place?
3. I'm not sure if the DP "the recently found chemical element" has the right structure. Can "recently" and "found" be adjuncts represented as AdjPs?
4. I figured that "appears" is a raising verb that does not need a PRO. However, I'm not totally sure of where the t(i) movement can end up in. Does it end up in the NP "compound" that has been moved up from the bottom? What can be the final position of the t(i) movement arrow?
5. if VP "created a compound" is replaced with "created on a petri dish", would it make a difference in the tree structure (since "on a petri dish" is an adjunct)?

If you could point out any other inaccuracies other than things mentioned on the list above, feel free to correct me. It's a flawed tree.

Thanks in advance.